# Case statement syntax MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I have a MySQL stored procedure that is working perfectly

```
BEGIN 
SELECT ID, SID, SerialNumber, SerialType
FROM orders
WHERE paymentStatus =  'Completed'
AND paymentSuccess =  '1'
AND VerificationStatus IS NULL 
OR VerificationStatus NOT IN ('Found', 'NotFound', 'NotVerified');
END
```

however I need to change it to return differently based upon the value that is passed into SerialType. I think a case statement might be the best way to do this, but struggling to find the correct syntax, and example below displays the logic and what I've tried thus far.

```
BEGIN 
SELECT ID, SID, SerialNumber, SerialType
FROM orders
CASE
    WHEN SerialType IN ('Var1','Var2') THEN
        WHERE paymentStatus =  'Completed' AND paymentSuccess =  '1';
    WHEN SerialType IN ('Var3','Var4') THEN
        WHERE paymentStatus =  'Completed' AND paymentSuccess =  '1' AND VerificationStatus IS NULL OR VerificationStatus NOT IN ('Found', 'NotFound', 'NotVerified');
END CASE
END
```

Comment: You pseudo code looks like an UPDATE,case returns one value

Comment: CASE is not suitable for what you are trying to do. You are changing `WHERE` condition not the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I wonder if your first query should really be:

```
SELECT ID, SID, SerialNumber, SerialType
FROM orders
WHERE paymentStatus =  'Completed' AND paymentSuccess =  '1' AND
      (VerificationStatus IS NULL OR VerificationStatus NOT IN ('Found', 'NotFound', 'NotVerified'));
```

Note the parentheses.

Second, I suspect you just want more advanced filtering for the second.  This would look like:

```
SELECT ID, SID, SerialNumber, SerialType
FROM orders
WHERE (SerialType IN ('Var1', 'Var2') AND paymentStatus =  'Completed' AND paymentSuccess =  '1') OR
      (SerialType IN ('Var3', 'Var4') AND paymentStatus =  'Completed' AND paymentSuccess =  '1' AND 
       VerificationStatus IS NULL OR VerificationStatus NOT IN ('Found', 'NotFound', 'NotVerified')
      )
```

This, in turn, can be simplified to:

```
WHERE paymentStatus =  'Completed' AND paymentSuccess =  '1' AND
      (SerialType IN ('Var1', 'Var2') OR
       SerialType IN ('Var3', 'Var4') AND VerificationStatus IS NULL OR VerificationStatus NOT IN ('Found', 'NotFound', 'NotVerified')
      )
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are trying to do something like this:

```
SELECT ID, SID, SerialNumber, SerialType
FROM orders
WHERE paymentStatus =  'Completed' AND paymentSuccess =  '1' AND
    (SerialType IN ('Var1','Var2') 
    OR
    (SerialType IN ('Var3','Var4') 
       AND VerificationStatus IS NULL 
      OR VerificationStatus NOT IN ('Found', 'NotFound', 'NotVerified')))
```

Comment: Correct answer, just 3 minutes behind Gordon's.

Comment: You mean 2 minutes before him )